# Lemma about infinite sequences we are hoping is true

Tags: infinite-sequences

Given N infinite sequences of non-negative integers, some of which diverge to infinity, must there exist two steps i, j in which $x_i \leq x_j$ for all sequences x?

Comment: Do you mean "all of which diverge to $\infty$"? Otherwise, of course not; take one sequence to be $x_n=n$ and the other to be $y_n=1/n$.

Comment: Assuming you want them all to diverge to $\infty$, yes. Let the sequences be $(x^k_1, x^k_2, x^k_3, \ldots)$ for $1 \leq k \leq N$. There is some $M$ such that $j \geq M$ implies $x^k_j > x^k_1$, by the definition of approaching $\infty$. Take $(i,j) = (1,M)$. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: In any sequence of non-negative integers there is a constant or an increasing infinite subsequence. Replace all of the sequences by the corresponding subsequences and repeat. Please keep hw out of MO.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Since I am working with integers, the 1/n shouldn't come into play.  Some of the sequences do diverge to infinity, and others fluctuate but never drop below zero.

As for the second comment, we need the same indexes for all of the N sets.

Comment: @LevBorisov, this is actually not HW, but a lemma we have reduced a theorem we need for CS research to.  As for "In any sequence of non-negative integers there is a constant or an increasing infinite subsequence" do we know that the subsequences for all N sequences intersect at all?

Comment: You do this for one sequence and then you ignore all of the other terms of other sequence. As a result you have just reduced the problem to situation where one of the sequences is nondecreasing. Then you repeat the procedure...

Comment: I imagine that assuming the existence of a counterexample would contradict the well ordering of the natural numbers.  Do you just need a proof in any socially acceptable system, or do you need a proof in a weak subsystem of arithmetic?  Gerhard "Ask Me About Forming Contradictions" Paseman, 2014.01.27

Answer (score 1):

So I think I found a proof thanks to the user picado on reddit:

For any sequence there's a subsequence $i_1<i_2<i_3<\dots$ with $x[i_1]\leq x[i_2]\leq \dots$ either because it's unbounded, or because if it's bounded there must be a value repeated an infinite number of times.

So take such a subsequence for the first one, and restrict all your other sequences to the same indices. Then the next will again have a subset of the i's as $j_1<j_2<\dots$ with $y[j_1]\leq y[j_2]\leq\dots$

Repeat N (finite) times, and you'll get a sequence of indices $m_1<m_2<\dots$ for all the sequences.

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant.

Comment: @LevBorisov ah totally missed the replace all the sequences with the subsequencs part.  Thank you as well for the help.

Comment: Sorry about the hw remark, the problem just looked very familiar. Maybe it is an old Putnam problem or something.